# How to fix texture issue in UWP

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have an AR App and I get this output before the development and after, dose anyone have any idea why is that happening after the development ?? or how to fix it ?
BTW: I'm developing for UWP [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A3VM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7BMG.png)

Comment: It looks a bit like the normals on the object are flipped. Googling for [unity flipped normals] may give you some pointers, [like this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/8177/flip-normals-of-an-object-or-make-material2-sided.html).

Comment: Could you post more information about your APP? Are you developing this APP for HoloLens, or are you developing it using MRTK?  More accurate tags allow for faster problem resolution.